# Finding process name that changes windows time

Tags: windows-server-2003, logging, time-synchronization

I have a problem in my server that the system time is automatically getting changed by a day and getting back to normal. I have some software installed for time sych. But the master clock seem to be fine. So I am suspecting if some other process is changing the time. I have enabled the event logging for time change. But it is not having the process name in it. **Is there a way to find the process name that changes the system time in Win-server-2003??**

Answer (score 0):

Run

`tasklist /svc`

on the commandline.

The svchost that hosts W32Time is your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect an ongoing process that's doing it, you may be able to check it for the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege. Process Explorer shows it on the Security tab of process details as SeSystemtimePrivilege, but you'd have to check that on a per-process basis. This may not help if a process is simply launching another process to update system time.

You may be able to work from the code in this Stack Overflow article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094663/determine-if-windows-process-has-privilege-to-create-symbolic-link to run a check for processes that have that privilege.

Also of note on Windows servers you shouldn't need third-party software for time synchronization - you should be able to specify NTP server(s) that the system will automatically sync to; if the server is disconnected from the Internet you should still be able to check against your DCs (if on a domain).

Also of possible interest is the MSDN information on changing system or local time (start from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724942%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server part of a domain? Is it a domain controller? In a Windows domain, the PDC emulator is by default the authoritative time server for the domain; all domain members synchronize with the PDC (via the Windows Time Service). The PDC is generally configured to sync with an Internet time source, by default `time.windows.com` which seems to me to be an unreliable source of time.

To learn more about the Windows Time Service, start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773061(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Just a minor correction, in a multi-site environment all DCs sync with the PDC emulator, and other domain members sync with their closest DC.